# Laravel cant seem to find path to some files

Tags: laravel-8, boilerplate

i'm new to laravel, and i just install boilerplate-gentelella admin theme. but it seems the laravel itself cannot find a path to specified files, for example when i try to register a new user, it went to an error

Unable to locate Mix file: /assets/auth/css/register.css. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\boilerplate-maxy-academy\boilerplate-maxy-academy\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)

i've tried to redo the installation steps but when it comes to running npm run dev, theres another error that says

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\boilerplate-maxy-academy\boilerplate-maxy-academy\node_modules\pace-progress\pace.js'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\boilerplate-maxy-academy\boilerplate-maxy-academy\node_modules\pace-progress\pace.js'
}

and im currently stuck right there

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.